# JavaFX CSS class not removed when node not parented

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I appeared to have discovered a case in JavaFX (8u144, running on Windows 7) where a TextField is rendered using the wrong style class.

This only appears to happen in the following situation

- style class removed whilst Node not attached to Scene AND
- parent `GridPane` has a style-class assigned, even if that class doesn't have content.

I've separated the issue from a larger application into the following contrived example:

```
public class RenderBug extends Application {

    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.getStyleClass().add("some-random-class");
        grid.add(field, 0, 0);

        StackPane stack = new StackPane(grid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stack);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/foo.css");
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Timeline line = new Timeline();

        line.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(4), event -> {
            field.getStyleClass().add(ERROR);
        }));
        line.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), event -> {
            stack.getChildren().remove(grid);
        }));
        line.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(6), event -> {
            field.getStyleClass().remove(ERROR);
        }));
        line.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(7), event -> {
            stack.getChildren().add(grid);
            System.out.println(field.getStyleClass());
        }));

        line.play();
    }

}
```

foo.css

```
.text-field.error {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.some-random-class {
    /** no content required */
}
```

Screenshot. At this point TextField is red, even though the class "error" has been removed. Even interacting with the field, resizing window etc. does not fix the issue.

[image: TextField shown with red]

Is this a genuine bug? or am I doing something wrong? I can't find any documentation to hint that style-classes cannot or shouldn't be updated "offline"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this is a problem on the [JavaFX developer mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2017-August/020684.html) and raised a bug report. Apparently this is a regression introduced in 8u102.

See [JDK-8185709](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8185709), which is apparently a duplicate of [JDK-8183100](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183100)

Comment: Discussion can be found [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2017-August/020684.html) for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183100 which is still in Open state